# How to pass a reference to layout guides from VC to custom view

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

When overriding the main view of a View Controller, what would be a clean way to refer to Layout Guides inside that view class?

Create a custom initializer for that view, that would take the guides as parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I would say delegate procedure would be the best here.

You avoid custom constructors which then enables you to use view in storyboard. Also by using delegate the values may change on your view controller and your view should still respect that and call for them only when needed.

To take a step forward I believe you could actually make that an outlet by doing something like:

```
@IBOutlet weak var ownerController: UIViewController?
```

So you could actually drag the view to its view controller in interface builder and assign the value to it.

But do make sure that the property is weak.

Comment: Thanks Matic! Good points, although I would not want my view to be aware of its View Controller. Unless someone comes up with a better solution, I will then probably restrict that knowledge to the layout guides (and since they would be a reference to the layout guides of the VC, I suspect the view would always be using the correct layout guides when it will be asked to layout subviews)

Comment: Well you could still create a protocol for it and implement that so it is not its view controller explicitly. Referencing the VC layout guides should not guaranty consistency (though they probably are consistent) so it is more proper to request them on demand. But in your case I would actually try to avoid layout guides at all and create a protocol that returns exactly what you need (height for instance). Top layout guide still needs VC while your view probably does not. And what happens when your Vc becomes embedded in navigation controller for instance...